# How to render HTML elements on PDF in browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, html, pdf

1. I need to render a PDF document in web browser (HTML5).
2. User should be able to make a selection for annotation (text or area).
3. Render html elements on the annotation (check-boxes, drop-down) received through ajax.
4. User's choice will be sent to back-end along with the selection/annotation made.
5. I should be able to render the annotations made again on the PDF.

Which frameworks should I use to create this solution? I'm happy to use open source frameworks as well as licensed SDKs. I can manage handling back-end using Node.js and interactions with ajax calls.

I did some research and found that I can use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) for rendering PDF. Found many solutions to annonate but they cannot be used to render HTML elements on an annotation. I'm happy to get [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) but no way to create html elements on  PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions and I'm really happy with them.

1. [Annotate.co](https://www.annotate.co/private-cloud.html)
2. [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current)

Almost everything needed is there.